# regular expression sub method does not replace all occurrences in python regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I was trying to use regular expression sub method but it does not replace all occurrences. Please see the below code. i wanted to replace all occurrences of " && " by " and ". Here there is a leading space and trailing space within the expression.

```
>>> string =" && && 7978888 && 896"
>>> tmp = re.sub("( && )"," and ",string)
>>> tmp
' and && 7978888 and 896'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use lookarounds in your regex since you have overlapping matches:

```
(?<= )&&(?= )
```

**Code:**

```
>>> string =" && && 7978888 && 896"
>>> tmp = re.sub(r"(?<= )&&(?= )", "and", string)
>>> tmp
' and and 7978888 and 896'
```

Using lookbehind and lookahead assertions here makes regex engine only asserts presence of space before and after `&&` without actually moving the current position.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is that there is only ONE whitespace between both &&'s.
If there were TWO spaces then it would work as expected, but why bother with including the spaces in the regex pattern?  Would "(&&)" not work well?

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = " && && 7978888 && 896"
>>> tmp = re.sub(r"&&", "and", string)
>>> tmp
' and && 7978888 and 896'
```

If that isn't enough, what other unique constraints do you need to follow?